# Help with Callout to external system

Tags: apex, callout

All, below is my code. While trying to make callout to an external API, I`m getting an error

> System.CalloutException: Exceeded max size limit of 6000000

synchronously.

I believe this is happening since payload that is being received is very large. I was wondering if there is a way to work across these limits. I tried using @future too however its giving me an error too

> "System.LimitException: Apex heap size too large: 12649268"

. Can someone please suggest a better way to get data in Salesforce?

```
HttpRequest obj = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    Http http = new Http();
    String reqBody = '{ "user": "test_user", "passwd": "2gbwefgnaiognawgona12" }';
    obj.setMethod('POST');
    obj.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    obj.setEndPoint('https://test.samplepoint.com/api/UserSrvs.svc/Login');
    obj.setBody(reqBody);
    obj.getheader('Auth-Token');
    res = http.send(obj);
                            system.debug('Oauth Response: '+res.getbody());
                           system.debug('Header Auth-Token Response: '+res.getHeader('Auth-Token'));

            authtoken objAuthenticationInfo = (authtoken)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(), authtoken.class);
            System.debug('objAuthenticationInfo: '+objAuthenticationInfo);


      Http h1 = new Http();
    HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
    String reqBody2 = '{ "Accountype" : "workforce"}';
    req1.setHeader('Auth-Token', res.getHeader('Auth-Token'));
    req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    req1.setMethod('POST');
     req1.setBody(reqBody2);

    req1.setEndpoint('https://test.samplepoint.com/api/accservices.svc/accountfeed');//URL will be your Salesforce REST API end point where you will do POST,PUT,DELETE orGET
    system.debug('======req1========'+req1);
    HttpResponse res1 = h1.send(req1);
    system.debug('==========res1============'+res1.getBody());
```

Comment: Realistically, if you're running straight into heap errors, you're not going to get this data in, in one pass, using Apex Code. Depending on use case, you might consider using the [ajax proxy](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Ajax_Proxy) to pipe data directly in to the browser to parse the data. You can then do things with that data in JavaScript, possibly including breaking up the message into digestible bits.

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox. I tried executing this code in batch apex and it runs fine with "success" message however I`m not able to see any debug logs. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: I'd bet that's because there are no debug logs (e.g. it crashed in a separate log somewhere). Using future and using Batchable should have the same effect. If you can't get your response under the maximum sizes, you can't use Apex Code to complete your goals.